# Confusion regarding kinds of question to be asked

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

I am a bit confused with the kind of questions that can be valid to be asked on SO. Many times I face such problems too, but then I refrain from asking them on SO, thinking its not fit to be here. Not related to programming, etc.

With no personal issue with the OP of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327013/how-to-determine-the-current-shell-im-working-on) question, I don't understand how this is a programming question. IMHO, its more suited for Super User. Why was it not closed/migrated?

**P.S.:** I am interested in knowing why it wasn't closed/migrated. This is to *learn* how to frame my such questions so that they don't get closed.

Comment: That example probably should be closed. StackOverflow's standards have changed, so many old questions which were previously considered good are now not.

Comment: You could just read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), which is pretty clear on defining the domain of potential questions. When in doubt you could ask anyway. You won't die from having your question closed.

Comment: It wasn't closed because it was from 2010 when things were a bit different and the site hadn't fully grown into what it is today. For better questions look to more current ones. If you can find a question that's been asked in the past 18 months or so that is similar in style / scope to your question and it's not been closed then that should be a good indication that yours would be OK. If you can't find anything similar then it's likely it's less suited to the site.

Comment: what's the benefit of closing it instead of migrating to superuser?

Comment: @eis It's too old to migrate anywhere now.  I can't remember the time period off the top of my head but I think that if a question is more than a few months old then it's not eligible for migration.

Comment: @Mario Eh!, ya! :P I won't die but then my effort and expectations get crushed :P I have been through the FAQ about qns to be asked, hence was surprised to find the question. Well, now I know. SO isn't now what it was before.

Comment: Also note that some of these types of questions were off topic when they were asked, but just didn't get enough attention to be closed.